# Check and add column in text file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a text file:

```
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5;;FIELD7;FIELD8;FIELD9;FIE‌​LD10;FIELD11;FIELD12‌​;FIELD13;FIELD14;FIE‌​LD15;FIELD16;FIELD17‌​;FIELD18;FIELD19;FIE‌​LD20;FIELD21;FIELD22‌​;IT0017;random information;IT0077;IT010‌​5;...
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5;;FIELD7;FIELD8;FIELD9;FIE‌​LD10;FIELD11;FIELD12‌​;FIELD13;FIELD14;FIE‌​LD15;FIELD16;FIELD17‌​;FIELD18;FIELD19;FIE‌​LD20;FIELD21;FIELD22‌​;IT0006;IT0017;random information;IT0077;NaN;IT010‌​5;...
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5;;FIELD7;FIELD8;FIELD9;FIE‌​LD10;FIELD11;FIELD12‌​;FIELD13;FIELD14;FIE‌​LD15;FIELD16;FIELD17‌​;FIELD18;FIELD19;FIE‌​LD20;FIELD21;FIELD22‌​;IT010‌​5;...
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5;;FIELD7;FIELD8;FIELD9;FIE‌​LD10;FIELD11;FIELD12‌​;FIELD13;FIELD14;FIE‌​LD15;FIELD16;FIELD17‌​;FIELD18;FIELD19;FIE‌​LD20;FIELD21;FIELD22‌​;IT0006;IT010‌​5;...
```

based on 3 fields: `IT0006` `IT0017` `random data`

- In the first row, I have `IT0017; random information;IT0077` but not `IT0006`(column_23) and `NaN` (column_27)
- In the second row I have all column(good case)
- In the third row I have none of those five column
- In the fourth I Have only the `IT0006` field.

I would like to create this output:

```
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5;;FIELD7;FIELD8;FIELD9;FIE‌​LD10;FIELD11;FIELD12‌​;FIELD13;FIELD14;FIE‌​LD15;FIELD16;FIELD17‌​;FIELD18;FIELD19;FIE‌​LD20;FIELD21;FIELD22‌​;IT0006;IT0017;random information;IT0077;NaN;IT010‌​5;...
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5;;FIELD7;FIELD8;FIELD9;FIE‌​LD10;FIELD11;FIELD12‌​;FIELD13;FIELD14;FIE‌​LD15;FIELD16;FIELD17‌​;FIELD18;FIELD19;FIE‌​LD20;FIELD21;FIELD22‌​;IT0006;IT0017;random information;IT0077;NaN;IT010‌​5;...
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5;;FIELD7;FIELD8;FIELD9;FIE‌​LD10;FIELD11;FIELD12‌​;FIELD13;FIELD14;FIE‌​LD15;FIELD16;FIELD17‌​;FIELD18;FIELD19;FIE‌​LD20;FIELD21;FIELD22‌​;IT0006;IT0017;NaN;IT0077;NaN;IT010‌​5;...
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5;;FIELD7;FIELD8;FIELD9;FIE‌​LD10;FIELD11;FIELD12‌​;FIELD13;FIELD14;FIE‌​LD15;FIELD16;FIELD17‌​;FIELD18;FIELD19;FIE‌​LD20;FIELD21;FIELD22‌​;IT0006;IT0017;NaN;IT0077;NaN;IT010‌​5;...
```

Getting the same number of columns...

- In first row, I added `IT0006;`
- In second row, never column (this is a good case)
- In third row I added `IT0006; IT0017; and NaN` (because I don't have information and use NaN …)
- in fourth I add `IT0017; NaN`

This is solution using PHP and good working:

```
<?php
$sapFile = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$typePers = array("Personale Viaggiante","Personale Interno");
$excludeFields = array("IT0006","IT0017","IT0077","Personale Viaggiante","Personale Interno","IT0105");
$emptyValue = "NaN";
$rowfinal = "";

// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($sapFile)) {
    $row = explode(";",fgets($sapFile));
    $substring = "IT0006;IT0017;";
    $lstr = "";
    $rstr = "";
    $type = array_intersect($row, $typePers);
    $keys = array_keys($type);
    if($keys == null) $type = $emptyValue;
    else $type = $row[$keys[0]];

    $j = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++){
        if(in_array($row[$i],$excludeFields)){
            unset($row[$i]);
            $j++;
        }
    }

    for($i=0; $i<22;$i++)$lstr .= $row[$i].";";

    foreach($row as $k => $v)
        if($k > 22)if(!empty($v))$rstr .= $v.";";

    $rstr = substr($rstr,0,-1);
    $substring .= $type;
    $substring .= ";IT0077;NaN;IT0105;";
    $rowfinal .= $lstr.$substring.$rstr;
}
$file = 'test.txt';
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $rowfinal);
fclose($sapFile);
?>
```

In the end, I must export files to CSV(add header column)

Can you help me to trasform in powershell script?

Comment: I try to be clearer:

This is correct case:
FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3;FIELD4;FIELD5;;FIELD7;FIELD8;FIELD9;FIELD10;FIELD11;FIELD12;FIELD13;FIELD14;FIELD15;FIELD16;FIELD17;FIELD18;FIELD19;FIELD20;FIELD21;FIELD22;IT0006;IT0017;Defined_Information;IT0105...
But I can have it other 3 cases:
1) H23 exists but not exist H24 & H25(In this case H25 must be set "NaN".
2) H23 not exists, but exists H24 & H25(in this case, certainly exists H24).
3) H23, H24 & H25 non exists.
I will definitely have H22 fields before.
Could help the top 22 ";" char..

Comment: What have you tried? (This isn't a code-writing service.)

Comment: I changed example...

Comment: *How can I create a PowerShell script to do that?* You open your preferred editor and start typing. As Bill already said: we're not here to do your work for you. Come back when you have a specific question about something in your code that you can't get to work.

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't propose previously solution. Now I have propose a solution in answer... and I hope that you help me to complete powershell script to normalize data.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that you miss only these fields in that order you can simply use replace operator with regular expressions (lookbehind + negative lookahead).

```
$text = Get-Content .\test.txt
$text = $text -replace '(?<=City;;\d{4};)(?!IT0006)', 'IT0006;'
$text = $text -replace '(?<=IT0006;)(?!IT0017)', 'IT0017;'
$text = $text -replace '(?<=IT0017;)(?!XXXXX)', 'NaN;'
```